# React-Testing-Library - Wrapping Component with Redux and Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-testing-library

I am trying to setup an test file to render a route/page on my application. I'm trying to wrap everything with Redux and Router, and this is what I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-testing-library';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import reducer from '../../store/reducer';
import {Link, Route, Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'

import ViewNode from '../Pages/ViewNode';


const customRender = (
  ui,
  {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...options
  } = {}
) => ({
  ...render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>
    </Provider>,
    options
  ),
  history,
});

test('can render with redux and router', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = customRender(
    <Route path="/server/:env/:nodeName">
      <ViewNode />
    </Route>,
    {
      route: '/server/prod/some.server.name.com',
    }
  );

  expect(getByTestId('page-content')).toBeVisible()
})
```

Then I get the following error:

`Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined]`

The reason this is throwing the error is because it cannot find the React Router params. It's failing in the component constructor when Im initializing the state:

```
this.state = {
            modal: false,
            activeTab: '1',
            imageStatus: "loading",
            env: props.match.params.env, //failing here
            nodeName: props.match.params.nodeName,
            environments: props.environments,
           }
```

It seems like it isn't wrapping the router properly with my implementation above.

How would I properly wrap my page component with Redux and Router so that it can get these router params?

Comment: @flppv, can you create a minimal git repo for the issue?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the question indeed not about minimal setup, I don't have a clue how to write a test for a component which depends on a lot of stuff around it - Redux, Sagas, Router, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have placed your `<ViewNode />` component inside a `Route` but forgot to pass on the props it receives. That is why `props.match` is undefined in your component.

You can do this instead:

```
    <Route path="/server/:env/:nodeName">
      {props => <ViewNode {...props} />}
    </Route>
```

Basically, you can use [one of the 3 ways to render something with a `<Route>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route).

---

Here is a working example:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'

function reducer(state = {count: 0}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count + 1,
      }
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count - 1,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  increment = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div data-testid="env-display">{this.props.match.params.env}</div>
        <div data-testid="location-display">{this.props.location.pathname}</div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
          <span data-testid="count-value">{this.props.count}</span>
          <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ConnectedCounter = connect(state => ({count: state.count}))(Counter)

function customRender(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({initialEntries: [route]}),
  } = {},
) {
  return {
    ...render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>
      </Provider>,
    ),
    store,
    history,
  }
}

test('can render with redux and router', () => {
  const {getByTestId, getByText} = customRender(
    <Route path="/server/:env/:nodeName">
      {props => <ConnectedCounter {...props} />}
    </Route>,
    {
      route: '/server/prod/some.server.name.com',
    },
  )

  expect(getByTestId('env-display')).toHaveTextContent('prod')

  expect(getByTestId('location-display')).toHaveTextContent(
    '/server/prod/some.server.name.com',
  )

  fireEvent.click(getByText('+'))
  expect(getByTestId('count-value')).toHaveTextContent('1')
})
```

[image: Edit react-testing-library-examples]

Comment: @flppv I hope this example helps you. You can also take a look at some of the [examples from Kent](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library-examples)

Comment: thank you, I saw all examples in repo and around the web. I never saw a really complex components tested, but now I have a few examples, I guess I have to do the same big boilerplate in each test.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I tested my routes.

- You use react-redux for the Provider
- You create the initial state for your store
- add it to your provider
- now you can select elements, expect them to match your html (per example)

```
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

    import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import React from 'react';
    import createStore from 'redux-mock-store';

    jest.mock('../../components/Form/ManagerSelect', () => jest.fn(() => null));

    describe('router page', () => {
      const createState = state => {
        return {
          //whatever u need
        }
      };

      const Home = _ => <span>home</span>;
      const Profile = _ => <span>profile</span>;

      const renderComponent = state => {
        const store = createStore()(state);

        //this is the "history" of your app like:
        // homepage -> about -> contact -> cart page ...

        const initialEntries = ['/'];
        return render(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries })}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        );
      };


      it('missing emergency details should redirect to profile', () => {
        const rendered = renderComponent(createState());
        expect(rendered.container.innerHTML).toEqual('<span>profile</span>');
      });

    });
```

Comment: So, in each test, if my component is a complex one I have to rebuild a big amount of wrappers around it each time, that's what I was wanted to know, thank you

Comment: No need to build all of that code for each test. Just take the component you want to test with the route path or whatever way you do it. Create a helper function that will create the above redux store and router that will just inject your tested component inside it. Something like: renderTestEnv(state, props, TesteComponent)