# Test suite failed to run. Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'reactBatchedUpdates.js'

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I am trying to get started on running tests on my create-react-app project. I keep getting this error 'Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'reactBatchedUpdates.js'.

I tried editing package.json by pasting this code into it.

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!<rootDir>/path/to/dir/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "coverageReporters": ["text"],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["my-serializer-module"]
  }
```

I assume that react-dom cannot be imported correctly for whatever reason?

```
const Header = ({clicked, open}) => {
  return (
    <div className="Header__Wrapper">
      <DrawerToggleButton clicked={clicked} open={open} />
      <SubHeader subHeadClass={'Header__Left'} urls={URLS.slice(0, 2)} />
      <div className="Logo">
        <Lock />
      </div>
      <SubHeader subHeadClass={'Header__Right'} urls={URLS.slice(2)} />
      <LogInButton className="right LogInButton__Wrapper"/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Here is the test code, simple rendering of my presentational header. I am starting to realize it is the way I am wrapping redux and react-router-dom over my component. I think that is my main issue at the moment. I am rather rusty on the inner workings of redux and react-router-dom. I tried following the example in this post [redux and react-router-dom wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803025/react-testing-library-wrapping-component-with-redux-and-router) but I am rather unsuccessful.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import {NAVIGATE_PAGES, SAVE_ROUTE} from '../../../../actions/types';
    import SubHeader from '../SubHeader';
    import Navigate from '../../../../actions/index';
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      page: null,
      route: null,
    };

    function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
      switch (action.type) {
        case NAVIGATE_PAGES: {
          return {...state, page: action.payload};
        }
        case SAVE_ROUTE: {
          return {...state, route: action.payload};
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    function renderWithRouter(
        ui,
        {
          route = '/',
          history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
          initialState, store = createStore(reducer, initialState) ,
        } = {}
      ) {
        return {
          ...render(<Provider store={store}><Router history={history}>{ui}</Router></Provider>),
          // adding `history` to the returned utilities to allow us
          // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
          // this to test implementation details).
          history,
        }
      }

      test('it renders lock', async () => {
        const store = createStore(() => ({ reducer: reducer ,initialState:INITIAL_STATE}))
        renderWithRouter(<SubHeader/>,{store,});
      })
```

I am just trying to render a simple presentational Navbar component.
However I keep getting the error below.

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'reactBatchedUpdates.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
    'utils/reactBatchedUpdates.js'
    'utils/reactBatchedUpdates.native.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

However, Jest was able to find:
    '../Login/LogInButton.js'
```

Comment: Can you add your test's code?

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx I added my test code. I am starting to realize its due to the redux implementation and my test setup for redux is likely incorrect. I tried to follow the SO link I added above but I still seem to be having issues.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you just render an empty `div` does the test pass?